# creating new array with combining same keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have following array. (A var_dump output) I want to combine those same key elements to single array. How do I do that?

```
 array (size=3)
      'totals' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => 
            array (size=1)
              'total' => string '4' (length=1)
          1 => 
            array (size=1)
              'total' => string '50' (length=2)
          2 => 
            array (size=1)
              'total' => string '44' (length=2)
      'styles' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => 
            array (size=1)
              'style' => string '11' (length=2)
          1 => 
            array (size=1)
              'style' => string 'aaa' (length=3)
          2 => 
            array (size=1)
              'style' => string 'bb' (length=3)
      'colors' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => 
            array (size=1)
              'color' => string '11' (length=2)
          1 => 
            array (size=1)
              'color' => string 'ccc' (length=3)
          2 => 
            array (size=1)
              'color' => string 'ddd' (length=3)
```

The final output should be like,

```
      'totals' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => 
            array (size=1)
              'total' => string '4' (length=1)  
              'style' => string '11' (length=2)
               'color' => string '11' (length=2)

     'styles' => 
        array (size=3)
          1 => 
            array (size=1)
               'total' => string '50' (length=2)   
                'style' => string 'aaa' (length=3)
                 'color' => string 'bb' (length=3)  

      'colors' => 
        array (size=3)
          2 => 
            array (size=1)
               'total' => string '44' (length=2)
                'style' => string 'ccc' (length=3)
                 'color' => string 'ddd' (length=3)
```

Comment: Please elaborate. Show your expected output.

Comment: I edited the question.Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

NOTE : It is not maintaining the key => becomes numeric array, but does the functionality.

```
        $array = array("total"=>array(array("total"=>1),array("total"=>2),array("total"=>3)),
                "styles"=>array(array("style"=>4),array("style"=>52),array("style"=>6)),
                "colors"=>array(array("color"=>7),array("color"=>8),array("color"=>9))

);
array_unshift($array, null);
$res = call_user_func_array('array_map', $array);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
```

output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [total] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [style] => 4
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [color] => 7
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [total] => 2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [style] => 52
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [color] => 8
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [total] => 3
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [style] => 6
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [color] => 9
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks so mushhh Bendra... You saved me lot of time... :)

Answer (score 0):

## Maybe this work

```
   for ($j=0; $j < count($your_array) ; $j++) { 

        for ($k=0; $k < count($your_array[0]) ; $k++) {
            if(!isset($sum[$k]))
            {
               $sum[$k]=0;
            }else{
                $sum[$k]=$sum[$k]+$your_array[$j][$k];
            }
        }
    }
```

so the same key wilbe combine, where ever size on it :)